# Does removing a partition automatically increase another?

Tags: partitioning, disk, format

Is it possible to format a partition and then converge it with the other partition so that the storage capacity of the other partition with the OS increases?

Actually, I am suffering that. I got two partitions on my hard disk. Both being 232 GB. I
actually wanted to know if all of 464 GB can be used with one OS in one partition only by removing the OS from the former partition?

Comment: No, those partitions will have to be merged.

Comment: Specifically the merging would have to be done manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete a partition it just becomes unpartitioned space. Depending on your partition setup you may be able to then extend the existing partition, thereby using up that free space. Without knowing specifics of your partitions it's impossible to tell.

Screenshot of what happens when you delete a partition:

Before = https://copy.com/wOy2HMKOffcz

After = https://copy.com/kDOl7RX0yJPx

## Steps:

Step #1

In terminal type `sudo apt-get install gparted`. [This is a partitioning program. You can use whatever program you want.]

Step #2

Open Gparted and choose the storage device you wish to modify partitions on. [It's in a list at the top right. If you only have 1 storage device then it will be selected by default.]

Step #3

Right click on the partition you wish to delete, choose delete, and click apply. [Apply is the check mark at the top of the program.]

Step #4

Right click on the partition you wish to extend, choose resize, input the size you want, and click apply. [Apply is the check mark at the top of the program.]

## Notes:

-If Ubuntu is running off the partition you wish to adjust the size of, you will be able to extend it, but you won't be able to shrink it. If you need to shrink it you can always boot up and Ubuntu livecd and do the partitioning using it.

-Never move a partition containing an OS. If you shrink a partition from the left to the right that counts as moving because you've changed the starting point.

Comment: Another warning....NEVER move or modify any partitions that are mounted on a running system.  You will lose all your data and it would have to be restored from backups (hopefully you do make these).

Comment: You guys are just wonders!!

Answer (score 1):

No, removing one partition will not automatically increase another. You need some partition manager software, like Gparted or fdisk. There you should remove one partition and resize another. You should boot into LiveCD/USB to use Gparted or fdisk because they require the partitions to be unmounted before doing any operation.